# Swift -injecting vars in ViewControllers

Tags: swift, appdelegate

I am proudly new to `iOS` developing and I am trying to build my first app. I am doing a course on an online platform which does the following in the
`AppDelegate -> application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
let navigationController = window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
let notebooksListViewController = navigationController.topViewController as! NotebooksListViewController
notebooksListViewController.dataController = dataController
```

This app has a `Navigation controller` which begins with an `UIViewController`.

I have 2 questions here, first is why this works, I mean, I am in `AppDelegate`, so the `NotebooksListViewController` (first view of the app) is not instantiated yet (I think), so why I am able to inject a variable in it?

On the other hand, the second question, is how can I do this in a different scene? I have a `TabBarViewController` as first scene, and the first tab is a `UITableViewController` and I want to inject the same way my dataController var, how can I accomplish this? I could not get to do it, neither understand it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It works, because of some Xcode magic:
In your *Target Setting*, *General* tab, the *Main Interface* entry specifies the name of the Storyboard to be loaded automatically when your app starts up:

[image: DeploymentInfo]

In the storyboard, the *Initial View Controller* then will be instantiated. It seems like this is an *UINavigationController*.
Since this is done automatically, it just works - until you want to do something special :-)

If you want to start up with a different scene - maybe from a different view controller - you could just change either the *Main Interface* to another storyboard, the *Initial View Controller* (inside the storyboard) or both.

Or, you could just start up by yourself, by leaving the *Main Interface* empty and create your own view controller inside the app delegate (`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`), something like

```
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
if let tabVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabCtrl") as? UITabBarController {
    self.window?.rootViewController = tabVC

    // Access the subcontrollers, or create them
    // Initialize their values
    // tabVC.viewControllers[0].data = ...

} else {
    // Ooops
}

self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Well, the app itself instantiate the Initial View Controller (I supose only this VC). I understand. But how to obtain the concrete instance in code? I mean in the upper code I could inject in a navigation controller, but could not get the instance of a TableViewController inside a TabBarController.

Comment: The tab bar controller has a property `viewControllers`, which is an array that holds all the child view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to your first question**

as the method name is self explanatory `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` means your application is didfinish with launching with options and its about to enter in foreground so here application need to set rootViewController so in this method controller you want to set as view controller is initiated thats why you can inject variable in it

**answer to second question**

```
let navigationController = window?.rootViewController as! UITabbarController
let VC = navigationController.childViewController
//Now Using VC you can access all you controller of tabbar controller
let notebooksListViewController = navigationController.topViewController as! 
NotebooksListViewController
notebooksListViewController.dataController = dataController
```

now as shown above you can use `VC` to access you view controllers

but be careful here because `VC` return viewcontroller array so you need make checks for perticular VC you want to access

Comment: Thanks for your help. In my project my Initial View Controller is a TabBarViewController which first tab is a UITableViewController, how can I get the instance?